# Ionic App behaving differently across browsers and devices

Tags: ionic-framework

I am building an Ionic App and i have been testing the app on Google Chrome Canary and it was working perfectly fine as expected. Recently, i tried testing the app on Mozilla Firefox and the app was behaving a bit weird like some buttons weren't working and the app was getting stucked. I ignored it considering that it might be an issue with Mozilla Firefox. Today, i installed the app on my device and to my surprise the app is behaving the same as it was behaving in Firefox. Some buttons aren't working and also the app is getting stucked. I need to release the app for production, as early as possible and i am stucked with this weird issue.
Please help me out.

P.S. - I have also added the crosswalk plugin.

Comment: what is the model and os version of device that you installed your app ? Did you debug your app for checking what kind of errors occurs ?

Comment: I am using Moto E and it is using Android 5.0. No, i didn't debug it yet. How can i do that? I am using Sublime Text to buld the app.

Comment: check this https://developers.google.com/web/tools/setup/remote-debugging/remote-debugging

Comment: Hey, hanks for the link...it really helped! It seems like I am getting two errors: 1.sqlite plugin database name must be a string and 2.TypeError: Cannot read property 'transaction' of undefined

Comment: I am using cordova sqlite plugin for my ionic app

Comment: good luck with this errors :)